# Error deploying MERN app on Render.com: ENOENT for index.html

Tags: node.js, deployment, render, mern

I'm facing an issue when trying to deploy my MERN stack app on Render.com. Locally, the app works fine, but during deployment, here's the log:
`Sep 24 10:06:32 PM  Model { User } Sep 24 10:06:32 PM  server is running on port 10000 Sep 24 10:06:33 PM  connection successful Sep 24 10:06:35 PM  Your service is live  Sep 24 10:06:35 PM  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/opt/render/project/src/invoicerfrontend/build/index.html' Sep 24 10:06:42 PM  ==> Detected service running on port 10000 Sep 24 10:06:42 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a port: [Render Docs Link]` 
My project structure looks like this:

• invoicerapp (backend)
• invoicerfrontend (React frontend)

I've tried adjusting the paths in my Express server's code, but the error persists. Here's the relevant part of my Express code:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, "invoicerfrontend", "build", "index.html")
    );
  });
}
```

I've taken the following steps to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

1. Adjusted Express Server Configuration: I modified the Express server code in "app.js" to serve the frontend files using the express.static middleware. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, "invoicerfrontend", "build", "index.html")
    );
  });
}
```

2. Checked Local Build: I ensured that my local build process (npm run build) correctly generates the frontend files in the "invoicerfrontend/build" directory.
3. Verified GitHub Repository: I confirmed that my GitHub repository contains the latest code, including the "invoicerfrontend/build" directory.
4. Reviewed Environment Variables: I double-checked that all environment variables, including those related to paths and configurations, are correctly set for the Render.com deployment.

Here's my GitHub repo for reference: GitHub Link

Comment: Your "github link" link is missing, but I would try:
SSHing to your service, and do some navigating around the filesystem to make sure that path your using exists for sure. And/or, add some `find` or `grep` commands during your build process that outputs filesystem details so you can validate the filesystem paths are what you think they should be.